# Reading audio spectrum from Video tag in html5

Tags: javascript, html, web, youtube, html5-video

I know there is a way to read the audio spectrum with Web Aduio API, allowing you 
to create a spectrum visualizer for playing tracks. 
Is there a way to do the same with Web Video API? I want to show the audio
spectrum of a playing html5 youtube video.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web Audio API works just fine with a `<video>` element as input. The code looks roughly like this.

```
var context = new AudioContext();
var source = context.createMediaElementSource(document.getElementById('video'));
var analyser = context.createAnalyser();

sourceNode.connect(analyserNode);
analyserNode.connect(context.destination);

// etc.
```

However, this will not work with a YouTube video for two reasons:

1) YouTube's `<video>` element is inside an iframe, and Javascript will not give you access to the DOM inside an iframe on a different domain from the parent page.

2) The video file referenced by an element will be served from a different domain, and the Web Audio API can only access video/audio files that either come from the same domain or are served with CORS headers. Even if you had access to the URL of YouTube's video file, it will not be served with CORS headers.

You're going to have to host the video on your own server.

Comment: But can't javascript access elements inside iframe? I think the other way around is prohibited - trying to access the host from within the iframe. 

Also, how come the video api won't allow CORS? After all most sites will use a different host for streaming or would like to embed the video.

Comment: Either direction is prohibited. CORS is allowed, technically, but YouTube won't enable it on their servers because they want you to use the iframe so they can show ads, collect stats and make it harder to copy the actual video file.

Comment: It's worth noting that even a year after this question was posted, support for `createMediaElementSource` is spotty in Safari. It's broken in 7, and I think iOS. Don't know about 8. And, of course, no Web Audio API at all in IE yet.

Comment: can someone give some example with a <video> element as input?

Comment: Connecting an analyser node is not mandatory according to MDN ;)