# How can I access the audio samples for the upcoming 5+ seconds from a <video> as it's playing?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, visualization, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm working on a [subtitle creation tool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/quicksubtitles/) and would like to add a feature that displays the next 5 or so seconds of the audio waveform as the video plays. I believe having a visual preview of the upcoming audio will allow the user to more accurately place in points for subtitles.

I found [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877155/reading-audio-spectrum-from-video-tag-in-html5) using an analyzer but it limits the audio samples to 2048 (about 1/24th of a second) which is too small to useful a preview.

I also found [this method](http://isflashdeadyet.com/tests/web-audio-visualization/) by catching "audioprocess" events but is still limited to about 16k of samples or 1/3 of a second. Again, not long enough to be useful.

I did a [quick test](http://jsfiddle.net/wcwqk2qy/) to see how long it would take to visualize 5 seconds worth of samples it's averaging in the low 20ms. So I think it's doable to process it in realtime provided I can access the buffer. I might have to lower the FPS but I think even at 15fps it should still be useful to the user.

Is there a method where I can access say the next 240,000 samples (5 seconds of audio) as the video is playing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body id="body">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="200"></canvas>
<script>

var count=0;
var samples=new Int32Array(48000*5);

var CANVAS_HEIGHT=200;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function processSamples() {
    var start = new Date().getTime();

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 200);
    for (var i=0; i < samples.length; i++) {
        samples[i]=parseInt(Math.random() * CANVAS_HEIGHT);
    }

    // We can't display each sample on it's own line... So take the average sample and display it
    // 1000 pixels for 5 second preview. So 200px per second. 48,000 samples per second / 200px = 240 samples per pixel
    var sample;
    for (var i=0; i < samples.length/240; i++) {
        sample=0;
        for (var j=0; j < 240; j++) {
            sample += samples[i*240+j];     
        }
        sample=parseInt(sample/240);

        ctx.fillRect(i, 0, 1, sample);
    }       
    if (count < 10)
        setTimeout(processSamples, 1000);   

    count++;
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var time = end - start;
    console.log('Execution time: ' + time); 
}
window.onload=processSamples;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this directly... I think you would have to buffer and process the audio via the Web Audio API, which might mean buffering the video yourself as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears at this time no way to extend the buffer to obtain a larger sample size during playback. However, I was able to generate a static waveform of the entire file via [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836447/generating-a-static-waveform-with-webaudio/25838151#25838151). I modified it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/daofw1g3/10/) to use the File API.

You load the file into an arrayBuffer and then pass the buffer a audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, callbackFunction)

```js
var audioContext = new AudioContext();

function drawBuffer( width, height, context, buffer ) {
    var data = buffer.getChannelData( 0 );
    var step = Math.ceil( data.length / width );
    var amp = height / 2;
    for(var i=0; i < width; i++){
        var min = 1.0;
        var max = -1.0;
        for (var j=0; j<step; j++) {
            var datum = data[(i*step)+j]; 
            if (datum < min)
                min = datum;
            if (datum > max)
                max = datum;
        }
        context.fillRect(i,(1+min)*amp,1,Math.max(1,(max-min)*amp));
    }
}

function initAudio() {

 var file = document.getElementById('fileItem').files[0];

 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onerror = function(e) {
  console.log("Error reading file");
  console.log(e);
 }
 
 reader.onload = function(e) {
  console.log("loading");
   var arrayBuffer = e.target.result;
        audioContext.decodeAudioData( arrayBuffer, 
            function(buffer) { 
                console.log("drawing");            
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                drawBuffer( canvas.width, canvas.height, canvas.getContext('2d'), buffer ); 
            } );   
 }

 reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

}
```

```css
body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
#canvas {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 800px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: blue;
}

#fileItem {
 position: absolute;
 top: 205px;
 left: 0px;
}

#button {
 position: absolute;
 top: 205px;
 left: 250px;
```

```html
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <input id="fileItem" type="file"/>
        <button id="button" onclick="initAudio();">Draw Waveform</button>
</body>
```